# Isolated point, but also limit point?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the set $A$ defined as follows:

$$ A := \left\{(-1)^n+\frac2n,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$

the two limit points of this set are $-1$ and $1$, because you can construct neighbourhoods arbitrarily close to those points.

But we can also construct a neighbourhood $V_\varepsilon((-1)^n+\frac2n)$ taking $\varepsilon = \frac2n - \frac2{n+1}$ such that every point of $A$ is isolated. What does this mean for the limit point $1$? It surely cannot be both a limit and an isolated point.

My idea is that for the first few terms, we have $1$ being a "pseudo"-isolated point, but as $n$ gets larger and larger, it actually becomes a limit point because we can construct arbitrarily small neighbourhoods centered at 1... pretty confusing to say the least.

This is exercise 3.2.2 in Abbott's Understanding Analysis by the way.

Comment: The point $1$ is not one of the points $(-1)^n + \frac 2n$. And $1$ is not a point in the set.  $1$ is a limit point but not an isolated point (nor a point of the set at all).  And each of the $(-1)^n + \frac 2n$ are isolated points but not limit points.

Comment: For $n=1$, $(-1)^n + \frac2n = 1$...

Comment: Oh, I see.  But for $n = 1$ and $\epsilon = \frac 2n - \frac 2{n+1}=1$ then $1$ is not an isolated point. As that neighborhood contains *many* points of the set.

Comment: It's worth noting that if $A$ is a non-empty set of real numbers and $x\in A,$ we have the following: $x$ is isolated in $A$ if and only if $x$ is *not* a limit point of $A.$

Answer (score 1):

> But we can also construct a neighbourhood Vε((−1)n+2n) taking ε=2n−2n+1 such that every point of A is isolated.

That only works if $n > 1$.  $1$ is not an isolated point.

$\epsilon = \frac 21 - \frac 2{1+1} =1$ does not lead to a neighborhood containing only $(-1)^n + \frac 2n = 1$ as the only point of the set.

The neighborhood contains infinitely many points of the set.

So that is an exception to the argument.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, your confusion stems from the impression that there is a *sequence* of points that grows with $n$. But in fact you have an infinite *set* of points, they are "all there".

For $n=1$, $V_1(1)$ contains an infinity of points of $A$ and is a limit point.

Comment: the op is say $a_1 = 1$ is a limit point and a point of the set.  If all the points of the sets are isolated points then $a_1 = 1$ is both.  (But $a_1$ is not an isolated point..)

Comment: @fleablood: you are right, I didn't notice the coincidence.

Comment: I didn't either.  (see the comments).